# Could bounty requests preserve paragraph spacing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I posted a bounty at [Why is my VSFTP server not serving up FTPS on 990?](https://serverfault.com/questions/822529/why-is-my-vsftp-server-not-serving-up-ftps-on-990) , and in the process broke up what I had to say into three or so separate paragraphs, intended both to distinguish my major points, and give some whitespace instead of a wall of text.

The text of my request is visible at [Why is my VSFTP server not serving up FTPS on 990?](https://serverfault.com/questions/822529/why-is-my-vsftp-server-not-serving-up-ftps-on-990) , but it's a wall of text. Perhaps some people will be sufficiently motivated by a bounty to parse through what my multiple points are, but I regard the undistinguished block as less readable than the whitespace-endowed message I tried to set out clearly to any parties interested in the bounty.

Could bounty requests preserve paragraph delineation the way normal posts do?

Comment: I'd want 50 UIPs just to read the bounty related essay.

Comment: You could (should have) put that wall of text (properly formatted) **into the question** and left the bounty notice as "This question has not received enough attention."